# Song played in Cardcaptor Sakura episode 54 at around minute 10?

Tags: cardcaptor-sakura

What's the song that's played in Cardcaptor Sakura episode 54 at 10:06? The same song is played again in episode 70 13:54.

I know it's not "Heartbreak" or "Tomadai"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The song is unreleased and it's called "Music Box"..

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZipZUsR_bSU